# Python using os and chdir to read and write to iCloud

Tags: python, icloud, jupyter-lab

I am using the following python code to access a folder in iCloud.  I am getting an error of:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/me/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/jupyter/')
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: In linux, the path string argument for os.chdir method begins without the slash character. Also, where is your script/shell python currently pointing the current directory? You can get by os.getcwd()

Comment: @ViníciusOA ? Absolute paths start with `/` on POSIX file systems.

Comment: @chepner I thought he could be invoking os.chdir in parent directory of `User`, that's why I asked what is his `pwd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no backslash in the directory name; you aren't using a shell, so the space does not need to be escaped.

```
os.chdir('/Users/me/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/jupyter/')
```